# Rails check nested attributes item is unique

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I've got a problem which is starting to make my head hurt. I can see a solution, but just need a hand getting across the line, or a completely different solution.

I'm using rails 4 and I've got 3 models.

- Project (has_many_users through collaborator, has_many_collaborators)
- User (has_many_projects through collaborator, has many collaborators)
- Collaborator (which connects users with projects)

A collaborator is added to a project via jquery, by searching for a user and then adding the user's ID to the DOM so that nested attributes does it's thing.

This all works, but the catch is that collaborators have roles and each collaborator may have multiple roles in the same project. For example, someone might be listed as both a photographer and a writer in different sections of the project.

At the moment a new collaborator is being added for each new person/role, eg John is added as a photographer, and then in a later section John is added as a writer.

What I want to do instead is check if the collaborator already exists and if so update the nested attribute instead of creating a new one.

One option for doing this would be to use Jquery after a user lookup and to do a second ajax call to check if a collaborator with the project ID and User Id exists and if so add the collaborator ID to the dom to trigger the normal nested attributes behavior.

This however just feels like a very clunky approach. What happens if the second ajax call fails? And it also means that because collaborators are added in many sections of the app this jquery / hidden field code is going to have to be added many times. not very dry.

What makes better sense is to add a method in the projects model or controller checking if a collaborator already exists.

What i'm trying to do is loop through the nested attributes of collaborators and add the collaborator's ID if it already exists.

I'm assuming I need to query collaborators for project_id and user_Id and if I get a match then add the id attribute for the collaborator?

```
project.rb

def collaborators_attributes=(attrs)
  self.attributes.each do |key,value|

    #How do I check and update the id attribute 

  end      
end
```

This approach may be in the complete wrong direction, so any assistance with it, or a new approach much appreciated.

Comment: Collaborator.find_or_create_by(user_Id: <userid>, project_Id: <project_Id>)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `find_or_initialize_by` :

```
collaborator = Collaborator.find_or_initialize_by(project_id: project_id, user_id: user_id)
collaborator.update_attributes(Hash)
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. So where can I use this code? Should I put it in my controller for create or update actions? Or should I put this in a method like I was trying before?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what i've got to work so far

```
project.rb

#Modify collaborators before save
def collaborators_attributes=(attrs)
  attrs.each do |key,value|
    #loop through collaborators and check if they already exist 
    if Collaborator.where("project_id = ? AND user_id = ?", @attributes["id"], value["user_id"] ).present?
      #if they do exist, add the collaborator id to the attributes
      attrs[key]["id"] = Collaborator.where("project_id = ? AND user_id = ?", @attributes["id"], value["user_id"] ).first.id 
      #I'm adding the project id here, but it may not be required
      attrs[key]["project_id"] = @attributes["id"]
    end
  end 
  #update or create new - based on of a collaborator id passed in attrs
  assign_nested_attributes_for_collection_association(:collaborators, attrs)
end
```

This feels very messy, but seems to work. I'm grabbing the nested attributes and looping through each collaborator to check if they exist. If they do I add the collaborator id to the attributes. Then I update or create new via assign_nested_attributes_for_collection_association

The only catch at the moment is that if I delete a collaborator, it deletes them from the entire project when it should really just un-mark them as a photographer, writer etc. I could solve this with a similar loop to check if any role added, but this is all starting to feel like a hard way of doing things. I think i'm going to go back to the drawing board and consider breaking the models up so that a collaborator just joins User and Project, AND a collaborator can have one of each role, eg photographer, writer etc.

```
  User
     Collaborator
         Photographer
         Writer
         Ect
  Project
```